# Random products added to order after checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, sales-order, magento-community

[image]

As stated in the title, after completing checkout on a test order and checking the order within the admin panel, the test order has random products added to it. What really confuses me is that the added items aren't in the product catalog, so I'm not entirely sure where they're coming from. They only show in the order after checking out.

Additionally, the customer inputted address isn't showing and is replaced by a default Magentech address. Obviously I would like orders to reflect what the customer has inputted so that I can ship their items to them.

I'm new to magento and taking over the work of another developer, any information that helps lead to a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to disable all the custom extensions and third-party extensions. Then place a test order. If issue fixed, then enable the third-party extension one by one and check which extension causes this issue.

Comment: Are they truly random, as in an unpredictable product, or is it the same unexplained product(s) every time? If the same products, it might be easier to find whatever custom code is responsible by searching for the sku/product IDs.

Comment: I will begin testing to see if it is an extension issue.

Comment: It is a different random product that appears each time. Sometimes it seems like a default/placeholder item, other times its Lipsum text. I kinda think its an issue with some custom code, issue is Im new to magento and dont know how to differentiate between default magento, extension, and custom code.

Comment: I depends on how the site was built, but directories under app/code are a good place to start looking for customizations. Other extensions are installed in the vendor/ folder. Unfortunately, it may be like looking for a needle in a haystack if you aren't familiar with the history of the site and what developer/vendor namespaces to look for. A lot of default functionality is installed under /vendor as well, and there is e en

Comment: . . .(continuing) the possibility that core code has been modified.

Comment: Well I guess Ill begin looking :')